# checkbox:hover + label doesn't work in Chrome 49,50

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have to following HTML:

```
<div>
  <input id="check" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="check"><span>Test label</span></label>
</div>
```

I want to style a checkbox + label  certain way. To do that, I use

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
```

to remove the checkbox, and then add a own custom box with:

```
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #baccdc;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 21px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**So, this works fine in every browser. Now, however, I want to change the style on `:hover` like this:**

```
input[type=checkbox]:hover + label {
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

This works in Chrome just after I clicked on the checkbox, and then, for a short amount of time, the `:hover` style appears.

In Firefox, this style always appears on `:hover`.

**[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0g9ud6ry/).**

> Is it a common Chrome problem or a mistake in my CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

label span {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #baccdc;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 21px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label:hover {
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="check" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="check"><span>Test label</span></label>
</div>
```

Try putting the `:hover` effect on the `label` :

```
<div>
  <input id="check" type="checkbox"/>
  <label for="check"><span>Test label</span></label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] + label:hover
{
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

Here is a **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0g9ud6ry/6/)** for the same

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have an issue with the `display: none;` state of the `input`.

Here's a workaround that works fine in Chrome too :

```
#groupInput label:hover  {
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0g9ud6ry/4/)

Comment: This will be applied to every label in the application.

Comment: Chrome 49 has an issue with almost everything.

Comment: Not sure if this was ever fixed but the problem is still in Chrome 57. I could have sworn this was working last week...